# Issue with image slider not showing images

Tags: html, css

I have an image slider that's not showing the images inside it properly. Not sure why this is.

Ideally, I'd like to have the images fit to the container. I've tried to change the inner slideshow image container's height and width properties but no luck.

Also when I navigate the slider, next image is not showing up, it is showing black background not the next slide.

Here is **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TaliZorah/47nf1159/5/)**.

```
<body>
    <div class="page-wrap">
        <header class="topbar topbar-grey">
            <div class="topbar-left">
                <div class="topbar-logo">
                    <a href="/"><img class="mysite-logo" src="http://lorempixel.com/output/cats-q-c-128-128-6.jpg" alt="Mysite Logo" /></a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <nav class="topbar-nav">
                <ul class="topbar-nav-main">
                    <li id="home-nav"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                    <li id="about-nav"><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
                    <li id="contact-nav"><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                    <li id="gallery-nav"><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
                    <li id="comissions-nav"><a href="comissions.html">Comissions</a></li>
                </ul>
                <div class="topbar-right">
                    <div class="hamburger"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/food-q-c-48-48-1.jpg"></div>
                    <div class="hamburger3"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/food-q-c-48-48-1.jpg"></div>
                    <div class="hamburger2"><a href="login.html">Login</div>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </header>
        <div class="contentstuff">
            <div class="col col1">
                <div class="box1">
                    <div id="box-image" />
                </div>
                <div class="box3">
                    <div id="box-image2" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col col2">
                <div class="box2">
                    <div id="slideshow-wrap">
                    <input type="radio" id="button-1" name="controls" checked="checked"/>
                    <label for="button-1"></label>
                    <input type="radio" id="button-2" name="controls"/>
                    <label for="button-2"></label>
                    <input type="radio" id="button-3" name="controls"/>
                    <label for="button-3"></label>
                    <input type="radio" id="button-4" name="controls"/>
                    <label for="button-4"></label>
                    <input type="radio" id="button-5" name="controls"/>
                    <label for="button-5"></label>
                    <input type="radio" id="button-6" name="controls"/>
                    <label for="button-6"></label>
                    <input type="radio" id="button-7" name="controls"/>
                    <label for="button-7"></label>
                    <input type="radio" id="button-8" name="controls"/>
                    <label for="button-8"></label>
                    <input type="radio" id="button-9" name="controls"/>
                    <label for="button-9"></label>
                    <input type="radio" id="button-10" name="controls"/>
                    <label for="button-10"></label>
                    <div id="slideshow-inner">
                        <ul>
                            <li id="slide1"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/animals-q-c-550-550-10.jpg" /></li>
                            <li id="slide2" />
                            <li id="slide3"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/animals-q-c-550-550-10.jpg" /></li>
                            <li id="slide4"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/animals-q-c-550-550-10.jpg" /></li>
                            <li id="slide5"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/animals-q-c-550-550-10.jpg" /></li>
                            <li id="slide6"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/animals-q-c-550-550-10.jpg" /></li>
                            <li id="slide7" />
                            <li id="slide8"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/animals-q-c-550-550-10.jpg" /></li>
                            <li id="slide9"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/animals-q-c-550-550-10.jpg" /></li>
                            <li id="slide10"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/animals-q-c-550-550-10.jpg" /></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="box4">
                    <div id="box-image3" />          
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <footer class="site-footer">             
        <div class="row-1">
            <div class="logofooter">
                <a class="logofooter" href="index.html"> <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/cats-q-c-128-128-6.jpg"></a>
                <div class="brand">
                    <a href="index.html"> MySiteLogo</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <ul class="legal">
                <li><a href="privacy.html">Privacy Policy</a></li>
                <li><a href="legal.html">Legal</a></li>
                <li><a href="disclaimer.html">Disclaimer</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="social">    
                <ul class="socicons">
                    <li><a class="facebook" href="https://www.facebook.com"> <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-q-c-64-64-10.jpg"></a></li>
                    <li><a class="twitter" href="https://www.twitter.com"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-q-c-64-64-10.jpg"> </a></li>
                    <li><a class="instagram" href="https://www.instagram.com"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-q-c-64-64-10.jpg"> </a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>   
    </footer>
</body>
```

Comment: What slider? Are you using a plugin? Are you developing in javascript your own plugin? Where is your css?

Comment: It seems working as intended.! Only one image with horse is not fit I think.!

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude Sorry it's in my fiddle, linked up top. I followed a tutorial and adapted it to my own needs.

Comment: The images inside don't cover the box is the problem I'm having. Actually made a fix to the loose <a> tag in my code. Here's the new fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/TaliZorah/47nf1159/6/

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is default img{max-width:80%} set in css.

```
#slideshow-inner>ul>li>img {
margin: auto;
height: 100%;  
width:100%;  /*set to 100%*/
} 
img {
/* max-width: 80%; */ /*Remove it, but note this will set all the images used in web page to 100%*/
max-width: 100%; /*Set to 100%*/
}
```

Alternatively ,

```
#slideshow-inner>ul>li>img {
margin: auto;
width: 100%!important;  /*this will override img{width:80%} */
}
```

Comment: Great will do thank you. Gotta go do something but will  a bit later on :)

Comment: Tried that there. It makes the first image ok but then when I click the button for the next or any other image it's all black? Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Above answer has nothing to do with the next images there is some other issue. Above code snippet just set the image fit in the box. You may remove above code from your css and try again. It is already all black there after the first slide from the beginning.

Comment: Sorry I think I need to change the way I asked the question. That was one issue, thanks for fixing that. but the inner slide show being black was the main issue. Sorry for not being clear about that.

Comment: What slider you are using.? Any source.?

Comment: Sorry took me a while to find it again but yeah it's this one http://cssdeck.com/labs/css3-image-slider